# How to create a block that shows recently viewed products/nodes for users?

Tags: views, rules, ubercart, flags

I want to make a block that shows last viewed products for users (logged and anonymous), using Drupal 7 with Ubercart 3.

First, I tried to use the [Recently read](https://www.drupal.org/project/recently_read) module. I don't why, but it's not working! Any changing in admin options (number of showing products and type of nodes) doesn't have any effect. And this block always shows ALL of my pages and products for all users.

Then I tried to do this using modules [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) + [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) + Session API. I found only a [manual](http://jan.tomka.name/blog/list-recently-viewed-nodes-drupal) for Drupal 6.  But in section "Select the condition to add - Check a truth value" and Views configure it's not similar to Drupal 7.

Can anybody help me to implement this functionality? Maybe you know, why the [Recently read](https://www.drupal.org/project/recently_read) module seems to not be working in my case, or maybe it causes some conflict? Or how to configure modules [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) + [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 1):

- [recently_read](https://drupal.org/project/recently_read) seems to have evolved
- or [do it with flag](http://jan.tomka.name/blog/list-recently-viewed-nodes-drupal) module (although not described in the linked tutorial, flag can also handle anonymous users)