# How to get taxonomy image and path by tid in Drupal 7?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, ubercart, entities

I want to get categiries image and path in Catalog Block for Ubercart 3 (Drupal 7) which is taxonomies. I know only `tid`.

<s>For path i try this</s>

```
$tid = (int)$variables['catid']; // return tid
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
print_r(entity_uri('node', $term));
```

but site crashed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're looking for something like:

```
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
if ($image_items = field_get_items('taxonomy_term', $term, 'field_name')) {
  $uri = $image_items[0]['uri'];
  $external_url = file_create_url($uri);
}
```

Where `field_name` is replaced with the name of your image field.

Comment: May be you can help me with this question? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/70847/recently-viwed-products-nodes